# Можно ли добавить требование обязательного указания номера issue при пуше в гит?

Tags: git, github, githooks

На гитхабе есть удобная штука: пишешь комментарий к коммиту, указываешь номер issue - и они связаны после пуша. Например:

> Добавлено логирование конвертаций. #50

Другое дело, что я иногда забываю проставить этот номер, хотелось бы какую то проверку прикрутить, скорее на стороне сервера, но можно и локально.

Вопрос - есть ли готовые решения?

Если нет - а как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(погуглить использование гитхуков), но я отвечу о минусах подхода "правильный коммит-месседж на сервер-сайде"

на стороне сервера - не надо.  если ты заставишь кодеров добавлять обязательные сообщения к коммиту, рано или поздно кто-нибудь сделает 120 коммитов локально, потом окажется, что один из коммитов (допустим, первый), прокомментирован неправильно.

закомитить нельзя. придется звонить/писать/ставить тикет тебе.

тебе посоветуют сделать rebase.  rebase не сработает, потому, что кто-то выше по дереву изменил структуру каталогов.

это трата времени. если хочешь энфорсить комменты, делай это на клиенте, чтобы человек, которому нужно что-то запушить _важное_и_срочное_ (такое бывает в продакшене боевом), мог сделать `git commit --no-verify`

P.S. серверный гитхук, который не запрещает пушить, но сам проставляет номер патча или другую инфу полезную - это вполне ок.

Comment: Спасибо, в целом разобрался хотя бы, куда смотреть. Если гуглить именно хуки, то быстро находится решение.

Answer (score 4):

### Visual Studio игнорит хуки, придётся коммитить вручную.

В папку `.git\hooks` нужно добавить текстовый файл `commit-msg`

Мне хватило вот такого простого (скопипастил [отсюда](https://gist.github.com/pgilad/5d7e4db725a906bd7aa7)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# regex to validate in commit msg
commit_regex='(#[0-9]+|merge)'
error_msg="Aborting commit. Your commit message is missing either a Issue ('#123') or 'Merge'"

if ! grep -iqE "$commit_regex" "$1"; then
    echo "$error_msg" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

На линуксах надо будет ещё разрешить выполнение:

```
chmod +x commit-msg
```

Comment: в смысле "игнорит хуки"?

Comment: @strangeqargo https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4321705-enable-client-side-hooks-when-committing-code-to-a

Comment: слушай, ну там уже три года уже прошло, неужели не починили? libgit2 вроде живой и vs тоже развивается

Comment: @strangeqargo ну бага libgit2 закрыта без реального исправления, а свежая студия всё так же игнорит. Видимо да, не починили.

Comment: а, почитал. это не столько бага, сколько "не наша фича", скорее студия должна это обрабатывать. интересно проверить будет с phpstorm/clion